# Uno Platform App on Linux Image not Showing

Tags: raspberry-pi, uno-platform

I am trying to get an Uno project running on a Raspberry Pi. I can get the basic project running but there are issues:

1. Use VS 2019 Uno Extension to create a cross-platform application.
2. Add an Image to the MainPage.xaml
3. Build
4. Publish Project.Skia.Gtk project to a folder on Pi
5. Run Project.Skia.Gtk from that folder.

MainPage comes up and text objects on the page are rendered. However, Image objects are not rendered.

In the Linux command window there is an error:

```
Windows.Ui.Composition.CompositionObject[0]
The member void CompositionObject.Dispose() is not implemeted in Uno.
```

Everything looks right on the UWP project.

Comment: The guide advises to put assets in your head project, i.e. into the Skia.Gtk project. Addtionally, I set `Copy to output directory` setting int the properties to `always` just to be sure.

Comment: Please provide a link to the guide you are referring to.

Comment: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/migrating-apps.html. Beware that Skia.Gtk backend is still in very early stages... I just found out the hard way that TextBox isn't supported yet :/

Comment: Tried your selection with no luck. Just to be clear, I created a Uno project from scratch and then copied the images over to the gtk project as you suggested. Things run fine on Windows, but I get the error on Linux.